# How to find all records from the db, where all values of the json field are greater than the current date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, hash

```
p = Post.last

p.change_dates = {'1': '2017-11-11', '2': '2017-10-11'}
```

`change_dates` can have multiple keys

I need to find all records from the database, where all values of the json field are greater than the current date

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Post.where("change_dates->>'1' = ? or change_dates->>'2' = ?", Date.today, Date.today))
```

Comment: yes, it will work. But I need "1" and "2" to be determined automatically, because there can be more such keys, not only "1" and "2"